# Android: SingleTop behavior with multiple intent filters

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I am struggling with the following strange behavior of SingleTop activities.

I have defined some intent filters in that activity:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.DashboardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="video" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <data android:scheme="survey" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
            <data android:scheme="call" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This code should start the activity:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    { 
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;

            }   catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {

                Log.e(TAG,"Could not load url"+url);
            }

            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    

        }

    });
```

in the onResume of the DashboardActivity I check for the according action:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        extras.putParcelable("uri", getIntent().getData());
        fragment = new VideoplayerFragment();

    } else {

        fragment = new DashboardFragment();

    }

    addOrReplaceFragment(fragment, extras);
}
```

But when I run this code, I always get the `android.intent.action.MAIN` action. If I remove the `singleTop` launch mode, it launches a new activity, but passes the correct intent. I have to use the same instance of the activity, so `singleTop`, `singleTask` or `singleInstance` must do the job. But I don't know what's going wrong here. HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())
```

Where is this intent coming from? In order to catch the new Intent you must use
[onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).